Is there a way to react to an input-signal's value as soon as it is set / changed without having to wait for ngAfterViewInit?
Usually you would use effect(() => ...) to react to a signal change.
Unfortunately it seems like effects only run as soon as the component is fully initialized and therefore during/after ngAfterViewInit.
In our case we have to sync component's input data to a scoped service as soon as the input is set and want to use it inside ngAfterViewInit already which does not work with signal-inputs.
The way with "classic" @Inputs has been to create a setter that runs before/during ngOnChanges. Therefore the data is already available during ngAfterViewInit.
Lifecycle order:

constructor

transform-method of signal-inputs

@Input setter

ngOnChanges

ngOnInit

ngAfterViewInit

Execution of inline defined effects (e.g. private signalEffect = effect(() => ...))

Execution of constructor-defined effects


So far, I have not been able to think of a better way to transport the data of a signal input to the service than using effect.
However, this will execute only after ngAfterViewInit.
Regarding (mis)using a signal's transform-method it would feel totally wrong. Nevertheless it would be executed at the expected time on setting the input. However, this is likely to cause problems with a risk that I cannot currently assess and it might also be not comprehensible for future development.
Using the @Input setter, on the other hand, is a tried and tested variant that processes data at the earliest possible point in time. However, deviating from the signal input for this is of course annoying.
I have not yet found a source online as to whether the problem should be approached differently. Unfortunately, an effect cannot be configured in this respect.
Converting a signal into an Observable + Subscribe does not change anything, as an effect is also used by the toObservable under the hood.
What are other people's thoughts on this? Should I just rely on the "classic" @Input + set or is there an unknown approach with signals?

According to signals documentation you should "Avoid using effects for propagation of state changes" - https://angular.dev/guide/signals. Only option I see is to use ngOnChanges

Thanks @m-g. Yes, we will take the ngOnChanges-approach. We would have preferred the Input-setter previous to signals for its concise data handling, but with signals ngOnChanges seems to be the way to go.

As commented by @m-g the way to go with signals seems to be falling back to ngOnChanges. It's maybe just a little less concise than Input-setters but should not have any negative effects on performance.
See also https://dev.to/angular/angular-setters-vs-ngonchanges-which-one-is-better-4f2b
So the final solution for propagating signals' changes apart from the (for the usecase of propagating data) unrecommended effect would look like this:
myData = input<ValueType>();

ngOnChanges({ myData } : {myData?: SimpleChange & { currentValue: ValueType }}){
  if (myData !== undefined){
    this.service.sync(myData.currentValue)
  }
}

